# How can I set the pricelist discount to a product when I create a sale order line? In Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have a function who retrieves *sale orders* from an external server.

Then, I insert each *sale order* with *order lines* in the odoo database.

Everything is inserted fine, except the **discount**.

I have the **pricelist** in the *sale order*, with a discount (for example, a discount of 10% in every product), but in all the *sale order lines* the discount is 0%.

If I add a *sale order line* manually, the discount appears correctly (10%).

This is my code:

```py
vals = {}
vals['order_id'] = downloaded_sale_order_id
vals['product_id'] = downloaded_product_id
vals['product_uom'] = downloaded_product_uom

new_line_id = self.env['sale.order.line'].create(vals)
```

I have entered in debug mode and realized that if I call some of these functions after the creation, the discount is applied

#### Option 1:

```py
new_line_id.product_id_change()
```

#### Option 2:

```py
new_line_id.product_uom_change()
```

But... why they are not called when I launch the **create** order?

Am I missing something in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have following options for set discount inside the sale order line while creating it from external server source.

1) Just set discount as like other parameter like uom, product, price etc from the source data of external server if you got discount value from their.

2) You have to call product or uom onchange method to set the discount based on the onchange calling and this is the default and safe method to set most of the data according to the onchange. It will not miss any special fields which are inside any customization with onchange method. I specially recommend this method to use if any discount data is not coming from external server source.

3) You can manage manually calculation of discount based on the external server source like price and qty etc. And set it inside sale order line.

I hope this is very helpful to you. Do not hesitate to ask any thing if not clear.

Comment: Perfect explanation. I did know the options 1 and 3, but the unknown part for me was the 2. Now it is clear :)